# Consumer-producer. No errors. Works sometimes. Why?

Tags: c, multithreading, buffer, mutex, condition-variable

1. Why this code give me different outputs every time?
2. Why it doesnt finish the loop?
3. What should I do to make it finish the loop? (despite context switches)?
4. Anything else I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 10

int buffer[MAX];
int fill = 0;
int use = 0;
int count = 0;

int loops = 15; 


void put(int value) {
    buffer[fill] = value;
    fill = (fill + 1) % MAX;
    count++;
    printf("putting %d\n", value);
}

int get() {
    int tmp = buffer[use];
    use = (use + 1) % MAX;
    count--;
    return tmp;
}

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t c_empty = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t c_fill = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void *producer(void *arg) {
    printf("producer starts\n");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); // p1
        while (count == MAX) // p2
            pthread_cond_wait(&c_empty, &mutex); // p3
        put(i); // p4
        pthread_cond_signal(&c_fill); // p5
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); // p6
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *consumer(void *arg) {
    printf("consumer starts\n");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); // c1
        while (count == 0) // c2
            pthread_cond_wait(&c_fill, &mutex); // c3
        int tmp = get(); // c4
        pthread_cond_signal(&c_empty); // c5
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); // c6
        printf("consuming: %d\n", tmp);
    }
    return NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("parent: begin\n");
    pthread_t p, x;
    pthread_create(&p, NULL, producer, NULL);
    pthread_create(&x, NULL, consumer, NULL);


    printf("parent: end\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
all: wcountb
wcountb: wcountb.c
    gcc -g -Wall -o wcountb wcountb.c -lpthread
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the main, you should call for `pthread_join`, like this:

```
  ...
  pthread_join(p, NULL);
  pthread_join(x, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Without that call, the threads are created and when you reach the end of `main()`, then your program terminates, thus your threads *may* be able to finish their job, or not, which explains the fact that sometimes your code works.

> The pthread_join() function shall suspend execution of the calling thread until the target thread terminates, unless the target thread has already terminated.

Taken from the [manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/functions/pthread_join.html) of `pthread_join()`.

An almost related question lies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675132/pthread-cond-wait-for-2-threads).