# In pthread, how to make a thread wait for a signal

Tags: c, pthreads

My objective is to create a thread that is reusable and not one that terminates when reaching the end of the thread function.

This is a pseudo code of what I'm trying to achieve with pthreads:

```
bool doRun = true;

void thread_func( void* p ) {
    while( doRun ) {
        waitForSignal() // just like waitForSingleObject
        // run thread
    }
}
```

I used the win32 function [waitForSingleObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) together with an Event in the past quite a lot and I have no idea how to implement that kind of behavior with pthreads.

Your help is appreciated

Comment: You're probably looking for [`pthread_cond_wait()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait).

Comment: Which OS please?

Comment: @alk the question mentions *pthreads* ...

Comment: @alk android jni c

Comment: @FelixPalmen: There is a POSIX thread port to windows.

Comment: @alk sure, but I think it's straight forward to suggest the POSIX threads method of waiting for a condition when the question asks about *pthreads* ;) (and we can probably exclude win32 anyways)

Comment: It seems you are using "signal " in a somewhat ambiguous manner, right?

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Well, the title does not mention "condition" but "signal" ...

Comment: @RonTLV, do you mean *signal* as in `SIGINT`?

Comment: @alk which is an abstract "signal to continue", as [`pthread_cond_signal()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal) would issue. I think this is quite obvious from the context of the question.

Comment: What I need is the exact behavior of waitForSingleObject( Event ) / m_event.pulseEvent(), or Java wait / notify, or Java count down latch.

Comment: @RonTLV that could be a problem in general, since those synchro mechanisms have 'issues', and replicating those issues will be difficult:)  I would use a semaphore, but maybe that's just me..

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33116597/6608866