# Is there a way to mass release threads after a certain instruction executes?

Tags: multithreading, semaphore

I need a way to release a bunch of queued/suspended threads at some point in the execution of function A (all at the same point) when a certain instruction executes in function B (updates a global variable those in function A would be using that is uninitialized otherwise).

I think that a semaphore could work, hypothetically, but in practice I’m not sure how to implement in this non-binary setting where I would like to release more than one (likely in the range of 16) threads after a certain instruction in another function executes.

Additionally, this sounds somewhat similar to the readers-writers problem, but I’m unsure how to extend it into my application.

If anyone has any ideas or experience with this, please let me know.

Edit: in C. Posix threads.

As an update, I may simply use a while(global-boolean) solution; though it would be nice if there were a way to suspend those threads in the meantime.

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: @Jeppe In C. Using posix threads.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098419/linux-posix-equivalent-for-win32s-createevent-setevent-waitforsingleobject